# Video Ads Scripts

Tags: javascript, scripting, video.js

I am creating a js file for video ads and using a number of scripts in it, those scripts work perfectly when used in html directly, but loading them externally (in a javascript file) doesn't ALWAYS work,
as at times some errors, like cannot read property getTech / registerPlugin of undefined, the player.ima is not a function arise otherwise.

Please guide me a possible root cause / solution for this error.

Code Snippet:

```
`var script1 = document.createElement('script');
script1.src = "//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script1);
script1.onload = sc1();

function sc1() {
sc1_loaded=true;
}

var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.src = 
"https://cdn.exmarketplace.com/bidder/video/video.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script2);
script2.onload = sc2();

function sc2() { //...
sc2_loaded=true;
}`
```

I added a function also to check the script loading, which says true.

Comment: Please add some code to show how you are loading the script in another js file

Answer (score 0):

`script1.onload = sc1()` will execute `sc()1` immediately and set `sc1_loaded=true`, so this isn't keeping track of whether the script has loaded. Use `script1.onload = sc1` instead.